# bash - get usernames from command last output

Tags: bash

I need to get all users from file, containing information about all loggins within some time interval. (The delimiter is : )
So, I need to get all users from output of command last -f.

I tried to do this:

last -f file| cut -d ":" -f1

but in the output aren't just the usernames. It seems to me like some record take more than just one line and therefore it can't distinguish the records. I don't know.

Could you help me please? I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

```
last -f file | awk '{print $1}'
```

If you want to use `cut`, say:

```
last -f file| cut -d " " -f1
```